# BizTalk 2009 XSLT and Attribute Value Templates

Tags: xslt, biztalk, attributes

I'm trying to make use of the [attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) type in a *BizTalk* XSL transformation to dynamically set attributes or other element names.

The following code is an example of an XSL template to add an attribute optionally:

```
<xsl:template name="AttributeOptional">
  <xsl:param name="value"/>
  <xsl:param name="attr"/>
  <xsl:if test="$value != ''">
    <xsl:attribute name="{$attr}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Problem:**

Running this script in BizTalk causes the following exception:

> "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)"

One alternative I thought about was to call a `msxsl:script` function to do the same thing, but I can not handle the XSL output context from inside the function.

An ideas?

Comment: Plase, provide a complete (but minimal possible) stylesheet and a complete XML document, so that when the stylesheet is applied on the document they produce the error. Right now we haven't your complete code and can only offer guesses what might be wrong in other parts of your XSLT code.

Comment: You don't have to escape your code. Just copy and paste it as it is, then select the code and press the Code-button (the one with ones and zeros on its icon).

Comment: See my answer for two probable reasons for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   <xsl:template name="AttributeOptional">
>     <xsl:param name="value"/>
>     <xsl:param name="attr"/>
>     <xsl:if test="$value != ''">
>       <xsl:attribute name="{$attr}">
>         <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
>       </xsl:attribute>
>     </xsl:if>
>   </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> Running this script in BizTalk results
>   in "Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)"

**Just me in "guess mode**":

**There are at least two reasons** there might be an error with this code:

1. The supplied value of `$attr` is not a valid XML name (e.g. `12345`).
2. The attribute is produced but the previously produced node is not an element (e.g. what is produced is `<someElement> sometext` then this attribute).

Comment: Dimitre, It seems that I misdiagnosed the root cause for the issue I am having. Im going to some more testing and will get back to you. My apologies!